# How to set the text in custom Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have been trying to change the text in the view which is inflated by custom alert dialog programmatically.In my app,the text in the custom layout should change according to various situations

I tried using setText(),but nothing happens.There are no errors either.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                TextView textView=(TextView)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText("Changed");
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);
                textView.setText("Changed");


                builder.setTitle("sdfdsf");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null).create()
                        .show();
        }});
    }
}
```

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Course"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Slot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8" />

    <TextView
        android:text="1205"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="94dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="D"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="81dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Oops using C++"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="94dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.knby.temp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
builder.setView(dialogLayout);
```

instead of

```
builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);
```

You'r setting layout twice.

Answer (score 0):

Change your this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);
```

to this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setView(dialogLayout);
```

you have add this line `builder.setView(dialogLayout);` instead of this `builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);`

Comment: @Piyush which one can you tell me ??

Comment: _you have add this line builder.setView(R.layout.dialog); instead of this builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);_. Again wrong edited

Comment: I just had to change it to builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);    Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Comment: Your answer will not be affected !

Comment: I just had to change it to builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);    Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

just use what ever you are using (Dialog , AlertDialog , Dialog.Builder ) like this :

```
Dialog dlog = new Dialog(this , your Theme ) ;
Dlog,setTitle("is this dialog ? ");
```

Comment: This is not the answer of OP s question

Comment: I just had to change it to builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);    Thanks though